# finding all possible flights from a starting point to a destination

Tags: c++, string, oop, vector, graph

> I recently tried to write a function that outputs all possible flight plans given a starting point from and an end point to that does not include any loops (no airport is visited twice). I will describe my basic approach to this problem below. Each flight plan contains a vector of shared pointers to a Flight, which has a name and connected two airports. Airports are represented as strings. The function I've been trying to write has the following signature

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FlightPlan>> allFlightPlans(std::string from, std::string to, 
        std::vector<std::string>> airports, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Flight>> flights,
        std::vector<std::string> visited_airports, 
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FlightPlan>> &route);,
```

where a Flight is a class with the public operations

- `std::string getFrom()`, which gets the airport the flight starts from,
- `std::string getTo(),` which gets the airport the flight goes to,
- `std::string getName(),` which gets the name of the flight, and
- the constructor `Flight(std::string from, std::string to, std::string name)`, which constructs a Flight object.

*Note that two flights may have the same name, but only under the following conditions: suppose flight1 connects airports A and B and flight2 connects airports C and D. If C and D are distinct from A and B, then flight2 may have the same name as flight1. Also, there may be more than one flight between the same two airports, as long as they have different names.*

I'm unsure as to whether it's easier to write the function as the following:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FlightPlan>> allFlightPlans(std::string from, std::string to, 
        std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> vertices, std::map<std::string, 
        std::shared_ptr<Flight>> edges, std::vector<std::string> visited_airports,
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FlightPlan>> &route);
```

In the second version, each std::string in the first map represents an airport and the vector of strings in the first map represents the neighbours of the associated airport. Similarly, for the second map, each string is an airport and each vector of shared Flight pointers is a flight starting at that point.

I will now describe my approach for the first version of the function. My essential algorithm for writing this function involves starting with the from airport and finding all its neighbours (flights that start at that airport), as follows:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Flight>> neighbours;
std::for_each(flights.begin(), flights.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<Flight> flight) {
  if (flight->getFrom() == from) neighbours.emplace_back(flight);
});
```

After I obtain all the neighbours, I call a helper function

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FlightPlan>> allFlightPlans_neighbours(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Flight>> neighbours, std::string to, std::vector<std::string>> airports, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Flight>> flights, , std::vector<std::string> visited_airports);
```

that checks each neighbour and calls the original function (the functions are mutually recursive) to obtain a route. It then appends this route to the result of callling the function on the rest of the neighbours.

The original function also has an add_each function that takes as parameters a from string representing the starting airport (from), a to string representing the destination airport (to), and a route. It adds a flight to each flightplan in the route to ensure that all routes produced are complete.

> I was wondering if there was a simpler way to write the function `allFlightPlans`, possibly one that uses different parameters and/or a different algorithmic approach? It seems my method is more complicated than it should be.

Comment: *but it seems it does not work in all cases, such as when there are multiple possible flights from the starting point to the destination:* -- So is it that your program is wrong, or the plan you were trying to implement is wrong?  If it's the former, then use the debugger.  If it's the latter, see where your plan failed and come up with a new plan.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry about that. I'm going to update my question.